# Проблемки с combobox

Tags: java, swing, jframe, combobox

Задача с комбобоксами: есть 2 комбобокса - в 1 нужно выбрать корм, а в другом животное, которое надо этим кормом кормить. И если выбираешь неправильно корм, то в jLabel появляется сообщение об ошибке. И все бы ничего, метод в принципе работает. Но есть одно но - в комбобоксе с едой есть пунктик "трава", он предназначен для лошади, и когда я выбираю траву и допустим кота, то программа мне выдает картинку с лошадью и чем её надо кормить, вместо ошибки. Вот код:

```
package animals;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class AnimalList {
    private String[] op = {
        "horse",
        "donkey",
        "cat",
        "dog"
    };
    private String[] items = {
        "овес",
        "сахар",
        "сено",
        "рыба",
        "валерьяна",
        "колбаса",
        "кость",
        "трава"
    };
    private JComboBox < String > c = new JComboBox < String > (items);
    private JComboBox < String > cb = new JComboBox < String > (op);


    private ImageIcon horse = new ImageIcon("horse.png");
    private ImageIcon donkey = new ImageIcon("donkey.png");
    private ImageIcon cat = new ImageIcon("cat.png");
    private ImageIcon dog = new ImageIcon("dog.png");

    private String hfood = new String("сено" + " " + "трава");
    private String dfood = new String("овес" + " " + "сахар");
    private String cfood = new String("рыба" + " " + "валерьяна");
    private String dofood = new String("колбаса" + " " + "кость");



    private JLabel l = new JLabel();
    private JLabel lblImage = new JLabel();
    private JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    private ItemHandler hd = new ItemHandler();

    public AnimalList() {
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        fr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        fr.add(c);
        fr.add(cb);
        cb.addItemListener(hd);
        fr.add(lblImage);
        fr.add(l);

        fr.setTitle("Чем кормить животных");
        fr.pack();;
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        AnimalList animals = new AnimalList();
    }
    private class ItemHandler implements ItemListener {


        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
            String s = c.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (evt.getSource() == cb) {

                if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("horse") && s.equals("сено") || s.equals("трава")) {
                    lblImage.setIcon(horse);
                    l.setText(hfood);
                } else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("horse") != s.equals("сено") || s.equals("трава")) {
                    lblImage.setIcon(null);
                    l.setText("False");
                } else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("donkey") && s.equals("овес") || s.equals("сахар")) {
                    lblImage.setIcon(donkey);
                    l.setText(dfood);
                } else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("donkey") != s.equals("овес") || s.equals("сахар")) {
                    lblImage.setIcon(null);
                    l.setText("False");
                } else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("cat") && s.equals("рыба") || s.equals("валерьяна")) {
                    lblImage.setIcon(cat);
                    l.setText(cfood);
                } else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("cat") != s.equals("рыба") || s.equals("валерьяна")) {

                    lblImage.setIcon(null);
                    l.setText("False");

                } else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("dog") && s.equals("колбаса") || s.equals("кость")) {
                    lblImage.setIcon(dog);
                    l.setText(dofood);
                } else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("dog") != s.equals("колбаса") || s.equals("кость")) {
                    lblImage.setIcon(null);
                    l.setText("False");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Укажите язык программирования в метках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в этом месте:

```
if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("horse") && s.equals("сено") || s.equals("трава")) {
    lblImage.setIcon(horse);
    l.setText(hfood);
}
```

У вас сказано: если выбрано ("лошадь" **и** "сено") **или** выбрано "трава", то ставить иконку лошади. То есть выбрав траву, при любом животном у вас будет показываться иконка лошади.

---

Чтобы этого не было, вам необходимо всего лишь поставить скобки, т.е. сделать если выбрано "лошадь" **и** ("сено" **или** "трава"):

```
if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("horse") && (s.equals("сено") || s.equals("трава"))) {
    lblImage.setIcon(horse);
    l.setText(hfood);
}
```